# Craze vs Craziness, are they the same?

Tags: synonyms

I'm a non-native English speaker, so is my friend. We are not literature students but we have our interests in English language and we do speak it to a decent level. He thinks we cannot use the word "craziness" in literature, we have to use **craze**. I disagreed because I think **craziness** is a valid word that describes insanity and perfect for using in literature.

After searching several online dictionaries, it seems to me that **craze** also has the same meaning as **craziness**, but normally **craze** is used to describe popularity of something while **craziness** is used to describe insanity.

Do these words bear the same meaning? Is my assumption about the usage of these two words correct? Is **craziness** valid for using in literature?

**EDIT**

Meaning of craze according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/craze?s=t)

Comment: They are different words with different meanings.  "craze" is synonymous with "fad", while "crazed" is a totally different word which is similar in meaning to "crazy".  Can you please include some urls for dictionaries that told you they meant the same thing?

Comment: @MaxWilliams multiple sites I clicked on defined craze as "craziness, insanity." But, I don't believe it can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Links to these sites please.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have added a link.

Comment: @MaxWilliams http://the-difference-between.com/crazy/craze http://www.dictionary.com/browse/craze http://www.thefreedictionary.com/craze

Comment: Interesting.  I have encountered "crazed" to mean "insane" but I've never encountered "craze" (with no d) to mean anything other than "fad".  Can anyone find any recent examples of people using it in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I can tell you that craziness is definitely a more common word. You're right that craze can refer to popularity, whereas craziness refers to insanity.

Craziness is defined as

> 1. The state of being broken in mind; imbecility or weakness of intellect; derangement;<sup>2</sup> insanity <sup>1</sup>.
> 2. The state of being broken down or weakened; as, the craziness of a ship, or of the limbs.<sup>2</sup>
> 3. The result or product of being crazy. <sup>2</sup>

So craziness refers to someone's insanity. It could also refer to a ridiculous idea or plan. For example,

> Person 1: Shall we just head straight for the finish line?
>
> Person 2: That's craziness! They'll see us coming a mile away.

---

Craze is defined as

> 1. Craziness; insanity;<sup>3</sup> an insane condition<sup>4</sup>
> 2. A popular or widespread fad, fashion, etc.; mania:
>
>    *The newest dance craze*<sup>4</sup>

So craze can refer either to insanity or to a new trend or popular fashion.

I think craze can be used to mean "craziness" or "insanity" if you explicitly mention that the said 'craze' is in and of a particular person. You could say that someone is *filled with craze* or *afire with craze* to emphasise their craziness. I would argue that either term is valid for literature and it really depends on what kind of ideas you want to create around the character.

Perhaps worth noting is the adjective form of craze: [crazed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crazed), which just means 'insane'. If somebody is insane, you could say that they are **crazed**; in a state of craze. An example that springs to mind is a Hearthstone card called [*crazed alchemist*](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crazed_Alchemist).

1. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/craziness
2. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/craziness
3. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/craze
4. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/craze